# Search in user defined type with Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql3, user-defined-types

In this example:

```
CREATE TYPE address (
    street text,
    city text,
    zip_code int,
    phones set<text>
)

CREATE TABLE users (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    addresses map<string, address>
)
```

How can I query users with `city = newyork` or find a user with a specific phone number.

Comment: I agree with the accepted answer that you should look into redesigning your data model in a way more optimal for Cassandra.   More broadly, though,  integrating Cassandra with Apache Solr allows for querying of non primary key fields, including user defined types:  http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchUDT.html (link is a guide to configuring UDTs in Solr for the DataStax enterprise Cassanra bundle which is not free).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really a problem of querying a user-defined type: imagine that `address` would be a single `text` column and that `addresses` would contain a single address (ie. `addresses TEXT`); the problem would be the same.

Your user table is not meant to be query-able by anything else than the primary key, which in this case is the partition key, which is a `UUID` which makes it quasi useless.

If you want to query the users by name I would denormalize (that implies some duplication) and make a `users_by_name` table:

```
CREATE TABLE users_by_name(
  name TEXT,
  id UUID,
  addresses whatever,
  PRIMARY KEY((name), id)
)
```

where the users are stored by `name` (they should be unique) and the results will be retrieved sorted by `id` (`id` is the clustering key part of the primary key).

Same goes for query by addresses:

```
CREATE TABLE users_by_name(
  city TEXT,
  street TEXT,
  name TEXT,
  id UUID,
  PRIMARY KEY((city), street)
)
```

You might think that it does not really solve your problem, but it looks like you designed your data model from a relational DB (SQL) point of view, this is not the goal with Cassandra.